# How can I upload a file in Nodejs using jquery ajax using multer (or other)?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, jquery-file-upload

I have a form that is outputting a JSON file to the backend with strings/numbers. I need it to output the image to the backend too and let multer do the actual upload.
I can use multer easily but not in ajax. The e.preventDefault() makes it harder for me, so I ask you to take a look at my code and explain what I'm doing wrong and how I can improve it.
Thanks in advance :)

```
//Form
<form action="/dashboard" method="POST" id="newproduct-form" class="row" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Product name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" placeholder="Product name" value="<%= typeof product_name !='undefined' ? product_name:'' %>">
                        <label>Price per unit</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price_PerUnit" placeholder="How many does one unit cost" value="<%= typeof price_PerUnit !='undefined' ? price_PerUnit:'' %>">
                        <input type="submit" id="submitNewProduct">
                        <a class="btn btn-success" id="backFormBTN">Back</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label>Product Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_Description" placeholder="Brief description of the product" value="<%= typeof product_Description !='undefined' ? product_Description:'' %>">>
                        <label> Product Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_Amount" placeholder="How much do you have of this product" value="<%= typeof product_Amount !='undefined' ? product_Amount:'' %>">
                        <label>Product Image</label>
                        <input type="file" name="productImage" class="form-control-file">
                        <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is some placeholder block-level help text for the above input. It's a bit lighter and easily wraps to a new line.</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>



//Ajax
$('#submitNewProduct').click((e) =>{

        e.preventDefault();

        productName     =   $('#product_name').val();
        pricePerUnit    =   $('#price_PerUnit').val();
        productDescp    =   $('#product_Description').val();
        productAmount   =   $('#product_Amount').val();

        //Front End validation
        if(!productName || !pricePerUnit || !productDescp || !productAmount){

            ajaxMessaging('red','Please fill all inputs');


        }else if(isNaN(pricePerUnit) || isNaN(productAmount)){

            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            ajaxMessaging('red','The Poduct Amount and Price per Unit fields should contain numbers only');
        }else{
            //Add new product
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/dashboard',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    product_name : productName,
                    price_PerUnit : pricePerUnit,
                    product_Description : productDescp,
                    product_Amount: productAmount,
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: ajaxMessaging('green', 'Submited') 
            });
        }


    });


//Backend using Nodejs and express engine
router.post('/dashboard', (req, res) => {

    upload(req,res,(err) =>{
        if(err) console.log(err);

        console.log(req.file);
    });


    const{product_name, price_PerUnit, product_Description, product_Amount} = req.body;

    var errors = [];

    //Check required fields
    if(!product_name || !price_PerUnit || !product_Description || !product_Amount){
        errors.push({msg : "Enter all fields"});
        console.log(product_name);
    }

    if(errors.length > 0){
        res.render('dashboard', {
            product_name,
            price_PerUnit,
            product_Description,
            product_Amount,
            errors,
        });
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Please fill all the fields');
    }else{
            //Finds the current user and pushes value into product array
            User.findOneAndUpdate(
                { email : useremail },                          //Find collection with same email as user
                { $push: { products: {
                    productName :product_name,
                    productDescription : product_Description,
                    pricePerUnit : price_PerUnit,
                    productAmount : product_Amount,
                }  } },
                (err) => {
                     if (err) throw console.log('found errors');
                        req.flash('success_msg', 'New record');
                        errors.push({msg : "New record in the database"});

            })
            console.log('Succesfuly uploaded new product');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Multer as middleware on the route, then return it as `req.body.FIELD_NAME` inside your controller function. You can pass a single field or an array, For example:

```
const multer = require('multer');

router.post('/dashboard', upload.single('cover', 1), upload.array('photos', 4), (req, res) => {

    const data = {
        cover: req.body.cover,
        photos: req.body.photos
    }

    console.log(data);
}
```

Also, before all, you can pass some config to it for better handling mime-types, file storage, etc:

```
// Config multer for using inside upload middleware
const imgStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/static/uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileExt = file.mimetype.split('/');
        // randomStringGenerator is my helper function to generate random strings with custom number of characters :)
        cb(null, file.fieldname + randomStringGenerator(50) + '.' + fileExt[1]) 
    }
});

// Create an image filter
const imgfileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

// Create an upload middleware
const upload = multer({
    storage: imgStorage,
    fileFilter: imgfileFilter,
    limits: {
        fieldSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Unfortunatly your piece of code requires that the browser refreshes which, since I'm using ajax, it does not. If you have a fix for that I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you should receive the file name like req.body.FIELD_NAME but you did not send and receive file input correctly, it just passed like req.file. Just send and receive your data like other fields. Name is just the object key you pass into JSON.stringify object. And what is the problem with e.preventDefault();?

Comment: if i do prevent Default multer's upload won't take place. Either way I already fixed it. thanks anyways